# I added a reference to System.Data.Entity but I can't use it

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I added a reference to System.Data.Entity, but when I try to use `@using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient` it tells me Objects doesn't exist in System.Data

Comment: Did you try `System.Data.SqlClient` ?

Comment: @MohammadTaherian i need SqlFunctions which exists under System.Data.Objects.SqlClient

Comment: Maybe the dll file is outdated?

Comment: Did you install nuget package `System.Data.Entity.Repository` ?

Comment: Got the code to work as part of a public static class.  Never did work on my *.cshtml